# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails while doing INSERT in a foreach

Tags: c#, mysql

While trying to add some items inside MySQL db i get the following error:

> : 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`articoli_ordini`, CONSTRAINT `fk_articoli_ordini_ordini1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_OR_ART`) REFERENCES `ordini` (`ID_OR`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)'

It seems like the foreign key i should add to the INSERT query is not found by doing `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but **the first item of the list is added successfully** while the next fails.

The MySQL tables to which i'm adding items are 3, `Ordini` let's say it's the parent table, `Articoli_Ordini` has foreign key on id of `Ordini` and `Varianti_Articoli` which refers to `Articoli_Ordini` so has foreign key on id of `Articoli_Ordini`.

The method where i'm doing all the INSERTs looks like this:

```
var query_ordine = @"INSERT INTO `ordini` (`TIPO_OR`, `ORA_OR`, `SENT_OR`, `ID_OR_CFG`) VALUES (@tipo, NOW(), 0, @cfg);";

using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_ordine, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", carrello.tipo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cfg", cfg);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qta", 0);
cmd.Prepare();

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return new StatusCodeResult(500);
}

foreach (var articolo in carrello.articoli)
{
    var query_articolo = @"INSERT INTO `articoli_ordini` (`TIPO_ART`, `COD_ART`, `QTA_ART`, `ID_OR_ART`) VALUES (@tipo, (SELECT CODICE_PRP FROM vo_plurep WHERE ID_PLUREP = @id), @qta, LAST_INSERT_ID());";
    cmd.CommandText = query_articolo;
    cmd.Parameters["@tipo"].Value = articolo.tipo;
    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = articolo.id;
    cmd.Parameters["@qta"].Value = articolo.qta;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    foreach(var variante in articolo.varianti)
    {
        var query_variante = @"INSERT INTO `varianti_articoli` (`COD_VAR`, `ID_ART_VAR`) VALUES ((SELECT CODICE_VAR FROM vo_varianti WHERE ID_VARIANTI = @id),  LAST_INSERT_ID());";
        cmd.CommandText = query_variante;
        cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value =  variante.id;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And fails on the second loop of `foreach (var articolo in carrello.articoli)`

Should I first store the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for `Articoli_Ordini` and even for `Varianti_Articoli` and use it instead of directly insert the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: You will have store the `LAST_INSERT_ID` of the parent. The 2nd iteration is using the `LAST_INSERT_ID` of the child query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's imagine you have 3 things to insert; one parent and two related children. You add the parent, you succeed in adding the first child, because you declare its parent id to be LAST_INSERT_ID and the thing most recently inserted was the parent so the thing returned by LAST_INSERT_ID is the ID of the parent..

But when you insert the *second* child, the thing most recently inserted was the *first* child, and LAST_INSERT_ID will change to telling of the ID given to the most recently inserted child record. This might even work, if there are more parents than children but you'll end up linking this child to the wrong parent

```
insert parent -> last_id is parent 1234
insert child1 as child of 1234 -> last_id is child 6667
insert child2 as child of 6667 -> either: works and links child to parent 6667 
                                  or: fails (no parent 6667)
```

So yes, you should insert the parent, SELECT its LAST_INSERT_ID and retrieve/store it in your C# and then reuse that cached parent id for every child you have to insert

---

Or better, use an ORM that will do all this for you, so you just have a Parent object with a list of two Child object, and you just say something like `context.Add(myParentWithTwoChildren); context.SaveChanges();`. Such software exists and will save you countless hours of wasted life, writing repetitive insert queries that are so boiler plate that they can (and should) be written by code, not humans

Comment: I didn't know that LAST_INSERT_ID() was getting the ID of the most recent inserted item, i tought it was like getting the last ID of the referencing foreign key table, while never heard about ORM but by reading right now something about it, it's seems to be very interesting would definitely try to use it!